# Android: How can I determine if Application starts with no signal or no service?

Tags: android

I have a phone state listener. I listen for service state, call state, and signal strength changes. This is all well and good.

BUT...

If my application **starts** in a condition with no signal strength, there is no "change" and I am not notified. I cannot, therefore, determine if I HAVE NO SIGNAL.

Is there a way to actively request/determine weather or not I have a signal or network service (not internet) on STARTUP??

Comment: By network service I mean the ability to make a call, not wifi or anything 'net related.

Comment: Use NetworkStateTracker and ConnectivityManager examples here http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java.shtml

Comment: I cannot use third party apps or APIs. :(

Comment: who told you that these thirdparty APIs?

Comment: you can also use this class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: Dev docs for [ConectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is, is that there does not exist any off the shelf Android methodology for this? I must incorporate, or duplicate the code you helpfully suggested? No simpler way?

Comment: Thanks. ConnectivityManager was what I was looking for. Will mark as the answer. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Mr.Awesome you can also use http://www.krvarma.com/2010/06/using-phonestatelistener-to-listen-to-state-change-in-android/  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html where the `ServiceState` object is used and evaluate the STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE flag meaning `Phone is not registered with any operator, the phone can be currently searching a new operator to register to, or not searching to registration at all, or registration is denied, or radio signal is not available.`

Comment: You know guys, I've been playing w/ ConnectivityManager, and it DOES NOT in any way, tell me if I have active/inactive phone service. I think it's geared totally toward the internet. If I'm wrong, can someone show me the code/method used to determine if I currently have active service? (so i can make a call?)

Comment: Try and use telephonymanager and phonestatelistener as I wrote it in my previous comment

Comment: PhoneStateListener is COMPLETELY PASSIVE. When my application starts...NOTHING HAS CHANGED. I won't get an OnServiceState change upon application start. I have no way to detect, at that time, if what the service state is until it changes. I am using PhoneStateListener. It works great! But it only feeds me info after my app has started and only when service state has changed. I need to know, IMMEDIATELY when my application starts, what my current service state is. ConnectivityManager, as you've seen, is absolutely no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (connectivityManager != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null)
{
      // Network is available
}
else
{
      // No connection available.
}
```

**update:**

You also need the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**update2**:

Looks like there are issues with connectivityManager so it's not 100% reliable:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11588

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11891

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11866

Comment: This is not true. My network returns null (i'm not on internet) but i have signal strengh and can make a call. The above is not true in the way y ou think it is.

Comment: Here is the info that getAllNetworkInfoR returns to me. 15 network types, all disconnected. I really think this is geared towards the internet and not the phones radio.\n  nwi length = 15
 Type: 0 Is connected = false
 Type: 1 Is connected = false
 Type: 2 Is connected = false
 Type: 3 Is connected = false
 Type: 4 Is connected = false
 Type: 5 Is connected = false
 Type: 10 Is connected = false
 Type: 11 Is connected = false
 Type: 12 Is connected = false
 Type: 13 Is connected = false
 Type: 15 Is connected = false
 Type: 16 Is connected = false
 Type: 17 Is connected = false

Comment: It's apparently a bug with connectivity manager on my device. It is not reporting the correct information. Thanks.